# change value of dropdown menu <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

If I say have the following  element, how do I change the selected value in it dynamically from jquery? (I know there are alot of threads of this subject here and I have tried them but I just coudn't get it to work)

```
<div class="styledDropDown">
    <form name="viewBeds" method="post" action="formhandler.cgi">
    <select name="title" onchange="javascript:showHideBeds();"> 
    <option selected value="All">All</option>
    <option value="Hannes">Hannes</option>
    </select>
</form>
</div>
```

I want to switch between these values so that the selected value becomes "Hannes" instead of "All".

How is this done easiest? 
Trid the following without success

```
function showHideBeds(){ 
    $('.styledDropDown').val('Hannes');
}
```

Hope you understood the question =)

Comment: `$('.styledDropDown')` targets your div and divs don't have values. Inputs do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) for the select element, `$('.styledDropDown')` is a `div`

This will do

```
$('.styledDropDown select').val('Hannes');
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npsrU/)

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$("select[name='title'][value='Hannes']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the current value with

```
$('#setSelectedOne').click(function(){
    $("#title option[value='Hannes']").attr('selected',true);
});
```

But I do not understand why you would do that with Javascript as the browser has its own do deal with Select boxes...